# Strange data while importing DEM and Contour files into blender via Blender GIS - addon

Tags: modeling, import

[image]I have been trying to import Digital elevation models as TIFFs, contour lines as shapefiles, and a few other things. but whenever i set the elevation based on attribute or import 'As DEM' i get long thin vertical data, seemingly projecting the whole dataset in the z plane like a tall thin rectangle. Has anyone had this occur, and if so how did you fix it? I am using all my data in WGS84.

Comment: Not clear what your question is.

Comment: are you using the fill non-data option?

Comment: Please add an image that illustrates your issue. Also, have you tried posting on the [github page](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues) for the addon?

Comment: added photo - if i import as a plane it shows up as the proper rectangle but its just flat

Comment: So it seems like my raster is coming in normally exagerated in the z plane, but the xy is 1000x too small. so if i change the z to strenght 0.0001 it works... but then everything is annoying to scale

Answer (score 2):

I just have the same problem yesterday, if you want to fix it, you need to change the right coordinate (CRS) in QGIS or ArcGIS first. For reference coordinate you can find it in google as free, because each area or zone has different coordinate.

Then, after do that, when you try to import .shp in BlenderGIS you can see in the bottom right corner in Blender after import it, change elevation so from geometry to Field and select elev field same as contour table in your open atribute table in you GIS software. OK.[image: Image of import .shp in BlenderGIS]

Or if you want the easier way, you can try to create contour from your DEM data to ArcGIS first:

1. Import DEM.TIF to ArcGIS
2. Create Contour from DEM.TIF
3. Create TIN from Contour, coordinate use Web Mecrator
4. Create TIN_LINE from TIN
5. Import TIN_LINE.shp to Blender

[image: Mountain Doldenhorn in Switzerland]

1. In Blender -> Click ur Contour -> GIS -> Mesh -> Delaunay

[image: Mountain Doldenhorn with Mesh]

Answer (score 1):

As you say your data are in WGS84, so the coordinates are in degrees instead of elevation values which are in meters... One degree on the earth is equals to approx 111km (at equator) so one meter is approx 0.00001 degrees.

You must project your DEM into a plane system in meters before trying to import it in Blender.